# Multiple UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hi Is it possible to create a Collection View with different scroll direction?

First section should scroll Horizontally and the second section will scroll Vertically.

I'm planning to create an app that shows the featured item image(array) in the first cell and user can swipe horizontally to see the next image and the rest is 2 cell per row and will scroll vertically.

[image]

EDIT: It should be treated as 1 view (for scrolling purposes)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can simply create 2 different collection views. One will has horizontal direction. Another one will has vertical direction.

[image]

Update:

If you wanna move out the top collection view. I'd recommend you to implement UIScrollViewDelegate on the second collection view (UICollectionView is subclass of UIScrollView) and when user starts scrolling just moving top collection view out.

[image]

Comment: can I embed it  to scrollview? So that when the users scroll it vertically, the horizontal collectionview will be hidden. see my edited post

Comment: why just not to embed horizontal collectionView within first cell of vertical collectionView?

Comment: @heximal yes, you are right. But I don't really like embedded collectionview that why I have recommended another way

Comment: @Arsen can you recommend me an article for scrollview delegate? I find hard to implement that.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll: you need implement only one method

Comment: @heximal tried that but I don't know how to link the embedded collectionView. Should I set the delegate and datasouce in the customCell(firstCell)?

Comment: no, you do things as usual, assign your viewController as delegate of horizontal collection view. it's not easy to describe in comments)

Comment: @heximal can we chat in skype or can I email you? Really struggling with my problem.

Comment: @Arsen how can I know if which collectionview did scroll?

Comment: @RonPelayo hey, I've prepared test xcode project for you. give me your email, I'll drop it to you

Comment: @RonPelayo let me know if it's delivered

Answer (score 0):

Ya, its posible to create two `UICollectionView`, first is top and second is bottom. set the scroll direction flow horizontal or vertical.

your design is created below,

[image]

select the `UICollectionView` then see right side, select the **Attribute Inpector** set the **scroll Direction** Horizontal or Vertical.

GreenColor is one `UICollectionView`, GrayColor is second `UICollectionView`. < and > is UIButton

Use the scrollview delegate methods its scroll top side

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

          GreenView.hidden = Yes;
          //update the GrayView frame its helpful

   /*     CGFloat x = self.mainCollectionView.contentOffset.x / self.mainCollectionView.bounds.size.width * SM_IPHONE_THUMB_CONTAINER_SIZE; // cell width + spacing 48 + 8
        CGFloat y = 0;
        CGPoint contentOffset = CGPointMake(x, y);
        self.thumbsCollectionView.contentOffset = contentOffset;


        CGFloat   x = self.thumbsCollectionView.contentOffset.x / self.thumbsCollectionView.bounds.size.width * SM_IPHONE_THUMB_CONTAINER_SIZE; // cell width + spacing 48 + 8
        CGFloat y = 0;
        CGPoint contentOffset = CGPointMake(x, y);
        self.mainCollectionView.contentOffset = contentOffset; */
}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: I need the two UICollectionView to scroll together when I scroll it vertically

Comment: How can I embed them in scrollview? GreenColor should scroll at top (hiding it) when the user is scroll vertically.

Comment: No GreenColor should scroll horizontal position, why you want vertical.

Comment: GreenColor collectionview very small  and what is your cell size, if you want vertical expand the height of GreenColor collectionView then verically scroll

Comment: No you didn't get my point. I need to hide GreenColor collectionview when the user scrolls vertically. so GreenColor and GrayColor should be treated as one view for scrolling purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111629/discussion-between-iyyappan-ravi-and-ron-pelayo).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add a first collection view on view controller   and add a header to collection view and add a another collection view on that and manage it with tag call the delegate method on the base of tag .

Answer (score 0):

While scrolling, do you want the top part (IMAGE) to be scrolled or remain there at top?

If you want it to remain at top than create 2 collection views separately. One horizontally scrolling other one vertically scrolling.

If not then create one collection view (which moves both horizontal and vertical) with items/2 + 1 sections. First section will have multiple items and have another layout so that it will move horizontally. And the following sections will have 2 items but fit to the screen so that wont move horizontally.

Comment: yeah I want the top collectionview to be scrolled when the user scrolls vertically. I think you can't set 2 scroll direction on 1 CollectionView.